# Find and conditionally sort all venues matching a filter provided by an API client in PostgreSQL

Tags: performance, sql, postgresql

I have an API where users can retrieve a list of "venues".

- Every venue is a profile, but not every profile is a venue
- Venues can be "parents" of other venues (think hotel - floor - room)
- When a latitude and longitude is given, the list should be sorted by distance
- When a latitude and longitude is *not* given, the list should be sorted alphabetically, by venue name (located in the `profiles.profiles` table)
- Clients use key-based pagination (i.e. a fixed number of results is returned per page. to get the next page, the client should include the first id of the next page - hence `LIMIT env.RESULT_PAGE_SIZE + 1`).

I have constructed a query, utilizing multiple CTEs and "short circuits" (`false AND condition`). However, I'm still quite new to CTEs and would appreciate some feedback on the performance of my query. I have also attached the query plan and would appreciate a step-by-step explanation of how to read it and what conclusions to draw.

**Context**

```
dansdata=# \d profiles.profiles
                          Table "profiles.profiles"
     Column      |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id              | text                     |           | not null | 
 type            | profiles.profile_type    |           | not null | 
 name            | text                     |           | not null | 
 description     | text                     |           | not null | 
 created_at      | timestamp with time zone |           | not null | now()
 cover_image_id  | text                     |           |          | 
 poster_image_id | text                     |           |          | 
 square_image_id | text                     |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "profiles_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "profiles_cover_image_id_idx" btree (cover_image_id)
    "profiles_name_idx" gin (name gin_trgm_ops)
    "profiles_poster_image_id_idx" btree (poster_image_id)
    "profiles_square_image_id_idx" btree (square_image_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "profiles_cover_image_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (cover_image_id) REFERENCES storage.images(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
    "profiles_poster_image_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (poster_image_id) REFERENCES storage.images(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
    "profiles_square_image_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (square_image_id) REFERENCES storage.images(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
Referenced by:
    TABLE "events.event_slot_participants" CONSTRAINT "event_slot_participants_profile_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profiles.profiles(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
    TABLE "profiles.individuals" CONSTRAINT "individuals_profile_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profiles.profiles(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "profiles.organizations" CONSTRAINT "organizations_profile_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profiles.profiles(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "profiles.profile_links" CONSTRAINT "profile_links_profile_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profiles.profiles(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
    TABLE "profiles.venues" CONSTRAINT "venues_profile_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profiles.profiles(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE

dansdata=# \d profiles.venues
                           Table "profiles.venues"
       Column       |         Type          | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 profile_id         | text                  |           | not null | 
 parent_id          | text                  |           |          | 
 coords             | geography(Point,4326) |           | not null | 
 permanently_closed | boolean               |           | not null | false
Indexes:
    "venues_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (profile_id)
    "venues_coords_idx" gist (coords)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "venues_parent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES profiles.venues(profile_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
    "venues_profile_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (profile_id) REFERENCES profiles.profiles(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
Referenced by:
    TABLE "events.event_slots" CONSTRAINT "event_slots_venue_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (venue_id) REFERENCES profiles.venues(profile_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
    TABLE "profiles.venues" CONSTRAINT "venues_parent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES profiles.venues(profile_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
Triggers:
    enforce_non_circular_hierarchy_insert BEFORE INSERT ON profiles.venues FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.parent_id IS NOT NULL) EXECUTE FUNCTION profiles.trigger_func_venue_enforce_non_circular_hierarchy()
    enforce_non_circular_hierarchy_update BEFORE UPDATE ON profiles.venues FOR EACH ROW WHEN (new.parent_id IS NOT NULL AND (old.parent_id IS DISTINCT FROM new.parent_id OR new.profile_id IS DISTINCT FROM old.profile_id)) EXECUTE FUNCTION profiles.trigger_func_venue_enforce_non_circular_hierarchy()
    refresh_venue_parents AFTER INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE OF parent_id OR TRUNCATE ON profiles.venues FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE FUNCTION profiles.trigger_func_refresh_venue_parents()

dansdata=# \d profiles.venue_parents
      Materialized view "profiles.venue_parents"
  Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 child_id  | text    |           |          | 
 parent_id | text    |           |          | 
 distance  | integer |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "venue_distance_idx" btree (distance)
    "venue_parents_child_idx" btree (child_id)
    "venue_parents_child_parent_idx" UNIQUE, btree (child_id, parent_id)
    "venue_parents_parent_idx" btree (parent_id)
```

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW "profiles"."venue_parents"(child_id, parent_id, distance) AS (
  WITH RECURSIVE parent_query AS (
    SELECT
      profile_id AS child_id,
      parent_id,
      1 AS distance
    FROM profiles.venues
    WHERE parent_id IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
      SELECT
        parent_query.child_id AS child_id,
        profiles.venues.parent_id AS parent_id,
        parent_query.distance + 1 AS distance
      FROM parent_query, profiles.venues
      WHERE profiles.venues.parent_id IS NOT NULL
        AND profiles.venues.profile_id = parent_query.parent_id
  )
  SELECT child_id, parent_id, distance
  FROM parent_query
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "venue_parents_child_parent_idx" ON "profiles"."venue_parents"(child_id, parent_id);
CREATE INDEX "venue_parents_child_idx" ON "profiles"."venue_parents"(child_id);
CREATE INDEX "venue_parents_parent_idx" ON "profiles"."venue_parents"(parent_id);
CREATE INDEX "venue_distance_idx" ON "profiles"."venue_parents"(distance);
```

**Query Under Review**

```sql
WITH
  root_nodes(profile_id) AS (
    SELECT profile_id
    FROM profiles.venues
    WHERE profile_id NOT IN (
      SELECT child_id
      FROM profiles.venue_parents
    )
  ),
  leaf_nodes(profile_id) AS (
    SELECT profile_id
    FROM profiles.venues
    WHERE profile_id NOT IN (
      SELECT parent_id
      FROM profiles.venue_parents
    )
  ),
  joined AS (
    SELECT
      p.*,
      t.*
    FROM (
      (
        SELECT
          *,
          -1 AS distance
        FROM profiles.venues
        WHERE ${filterModel.near && 1}::int IS NULL
      )
      UNION ALL
      (
        SELECT
          *,
          ST_DistanceSphere(
            coords::geometry,
            ST_MakePoint(${filterModel.near?.lng ?? 0}, ${filterModel.near?.lat ?? 0})
          ) AS distance
        FROM profiles.venues
        WHERE ${filterModel.near && 1}::int IS NOT NULL
      ) 
    ) AS t
    INNER JOIN profiles.profiles p
      ON p.id = t.profile_id
  ),
  sorted AS (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM joined
    ORDER BY
        distance ASC,
        name ASC,
        id ASC
  ),
  enumerated AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS index
    FROM sorted
  )
SELECT id AS "profileId"
FROM enumerated
WHERE (
  ${filterModel.includePermanentlyClosed}
  OR permanently_closed = FALSE          
) AND (
  ${filterModel.level === "any"}
  OR (
    ${filterModel.level === "root"}
    AND profile_id IN (SELECT * FROM root_nodes)
  )
  OR (
    ${filterModel.level === "leaf"}
    AND profile_id IN (SELECT * FROM leaf_nodes)
  )
) AND (
  index >= COALESCE(
    (
      SELECT index
      FROM enumerated
      WHERE id = ${filterModel.pageKey}
    ),
    0
  )
)
ORDER BY index
LIMIT ${env.RESULT_PAGE_SIZE + 1}
```

**Example with actual values**

```
    ┌──────────────────────────┬───────────────────┬────────────────────┬────────┐
    │         (index)          │        lat        │        lng         │ Values │
    ├──────────────────────────┼───────────────────┼────────────────────┼────────┤
    │  env.RESULT_PAGE_SIZE.   │                   │                    │   30   │
    │          level           │                   │                    │ 'any'  │
    │ includePermanentlyClosed │                   │                    │  true  │
    │           near           │ 58.41616195587502 │ 15.625933242341707 │        │
    └──────────────────────────┴───────────────────┴────────────────────┴────────┘
```

```sql
WITH
  root_nodes(profile_id) AS (
    SELECT profile_id
    FROM profiles.venues
    WHERE profile_id NOT IN (
      SELECT child_id
      FROM profiles.venue_parents
    )
  ),
  leaf_nodes(profile_id) AS (
    SELECT profile_id
    FROM profiles.venues
    WHERE profile_id NOT IN (
      SELECT parent_id
      FROM profiles.venue_parents
    )
  ),
  joined AS (
    SELECT
      p.*,
      t.*
    FROM (
      (
        SELECT
          *,
          -1 AS distance
        FROM profiles.venues
        WHERE 1::int IS NULL
      )
      UNION ALL
      (
        SELECT
          *,
          ST_DistanceSphere(
            coords::geometry,
            ST_MakePoint(15.625933242341707, 58.41616195587502)
          ) AS distance
        FROM profiles.venues
        WHERE 1::int IS NOT NULL
      ) 
    ) AS t
    INNER JOIN profiles.profiles p
      ON p.id = t.profile_id
  ),
  sorted AS (
    SELECT
      *
    FROM joined
    ORDER BY
        distance ASC,
        name ASC,
        id ASC
  ),
  enumerated AS (
    SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS index
    FROM sorted
  )
SELECT id AS "profileId"
FROM enumerated
WHERE (
  true
  OR permanently_closed = FALSE          
) AND (
  true
  OR (
    false
    AND profile_id IN (SELECT * FROM root_nodes)
  )
  OR (
    false
    AND profile_id IN (SELECT * FROM leaf_nodes)
  )
) AND (
  index >= COALESCE(
    (
      SELECT index
      FROM enumerated
      WHERE id = null
    ),
    0
  )
)
ORDER BY index
LIMIT 31
```

**Query Plan**

Output from `EXPLAIN ...`, given the above example with actual values and run on a database instance with only 1 profile, which is not a venue.

```
                                            QUERY PLAN                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=8248.43..8248.51 rows=31 width=40)
   CTE enumerated
     ->  WindowAgg  (cost=8211.05..8227.32 rows=651 width=317)
           ->  Sort  (cost=8211.05..8212.67 rows=651 width=309)
                 Sort Key: (('-1'::integer)::double precision), p.name, p.id
                 ->  Hash Join  (cost=17.88..8180.62 rows=651 width=309)
                       Hash Cond: ("*SELECT* 1".profile_id = p.id)
                       ->  Append  (cost=0.00..8154.51 rows=651 width=105)
                             ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=105)
                                   ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=101)
                                         One-Time Filter: false
                             ->  Seq Scan on venues  (cost=0.00..8144.75 rows=650 width=105)
                       ->  Hash  (cost=13.50..13.50 rows=350 width=204)
                             ->  Seq Scan on profiles p  (cost=0.00..13.50 rows=350 width=204)
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=0 width=0)
           One-Time Filter: false
   ->  Sort  (cost=21.11..21.65 rows=217 width=40)
         Sort Key: enumerated.index
         ->  CTE Scan on enumerated  (cost=0.00..14.65 rows=217 width=40)
               Filter: (index >= COALESCE($1, '0'::bigint))
(21 rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## distance

Here's a curious column:

```
      Materialized view "profiles.venue_parents"
  Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-----------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 ...
 distance  | integer |           |          |
```

Distance to what?
[Charing Cross](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charing_Cross)?
Linköping Central Station?
Document the origin point.

Or better, include the pair of (lat, long)'s, for total of five columns,
and then you'll have a self-documenting relation.

I *am* glad to see it's in SI units of meters.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW venue_parents ...
      ...
      1 AS distance ...
```

Why a sentinel of one meter, rather than zero?

You seem to sum up `+1` and `-1` a fair amount -- what does that mean?
Maybe you wanted a different word, like `priority`, to describe
your ORDER BY preference, if we don't have actual geographic distances here.

---

## long query

Your WITH root_nodes... query is Too Long.
Maybe you can keep all those plates spinning in the air at once, but I can't.
Consider breaking out meaningful relations, giving them names,
and defining each as a VIEW.
Then this long query becomes a much simpler combination of the VIEWs you built up.

Such decomposition doesn't really matter to the backend query planner --
it will catenate them together and still produce plans similar to the current one.
The advantage is that you get to do piecewise debugging,
of both a result's correctness and also its performance.

Also, the VIEWs would hopefully discourage you from sprinkling
expressions like `${filterModel.near?.lng ?? 0}`
and `${filterModel.near && 1}::int` throughout the interior
of your queries.
Have the query surface attributes like a longitude column,
and then let your UI interface select rows WHERE longitude has some value,
or perhaps WHERE ST_DistanceSphere() has some value.

---

## meaningful names

```
    ...
    ) AS t
```

That's not really helping me out.
Give it a proper name, describe the relation you just built.

With `p.*` you at least told us it's the `profiles` table,
so I know how to mentally pronounce it.

---

## query plan

You didn't mention any symptoms like only getting X result rows per second,
or having to wait Y seconds for first result row to appear.
Mostly it all looks good to me.

You can use
[EXPLAIN ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html)
for more detailed timings.
The EXPLAIN will comment on "how many rows?" and "is there an index?",
without actually fetching rows.
An ANALYZE *will* fetch the rows, and measure how many seconds that took.

Planning only becomes interesting when you have "lots" of data,
and most of it remains on-disk, ignored by a query that looks
for just a narrow range of result values.
You appear to have only a small amount of data,
less than seven hundred rows,
which suggests that all queries would be fast,
even if there were no indexes.
INSERT more rows if you want to explore performance in depth.

The plan, and the use of indexes, mostly looks fine.
The only noteworthy item that leaps out at me is this tablescan:

```
         ->  Seq Scan on venues  (cost=0.00..8144.75 rows=650 width=105)
```

And of course tablescans are not a bad thing, sometimes that's the
very best access plan, if your query needs to retrieve every single stored value.

If we're focused on nice snappy interactive response times, then query
[selectivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_optimization#Cost_estimation)
is something you want to pay attention to.
A highly selective WHERE clause is one that lets us retrieve just a handful
of rows to obtain a result, while we get to ignore 99% of a table's contents.
Usually some suitable index will help us achieve that.
In contrast a low selectivity query forces the backend to retrieve
most of the rows, and there's just no optimizing that, it fundamentally
requires doing a lot of time consuming work.

Your query is on the complex side.
Think about how storing certain facts in a reporting table
would allow you to submit a query that is both simpler for the backend to plan
and easier for humans to reason about.

---

## sql92 keywords

I'm not fond of naming a column `index`,
given that that is a pretty important part of
[DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language).
Prefer an alternate spelling, perhaps `idx`.

---

## paging

Assume that each interactive user has a unique ID,
perhaps a GUID in a web session cookie.
Equivalently, we could use hash of the first
part of a query, omitting the page number.

You run a complex query and then return just the subset
of result rows that fall within the requested page.
And then re-run it for the subsequent page.

Consider caching the full result set in a reporting table,
indexed on guid + row number.
Now satisfying a 2nd page or 3rd page request becomes trivial.

Put a timestamp in such rows, so you can purge yesterday's trash.

Depending on user behavior, maybe don't bother with
storing results for 1st page requests, if users
typically jump around while looking only at 1st page results
(so any 2nd page effort would typically be wasted).
Once you see a 2nd page request, that may be a fair indicator
that user will soon generate 3rd page and 4th page requests, as well.

Comment: Wow, thank you for taking the time to write such an in-depth answer! I see there is some confusion about a few things - I'll try to clarify here, but in general you have some really good points that I'll make sure to implement. Thanks!

Comment: `distance` - distance in the `venue_parents` view refers to node distance in the venue tree. For example, The node distance between "hotel" and "room" in the tree "hotel - floor - room" would be `2`.

Comment: `1 AS distance` [...] Why a sentinel of one meter, rather than zero? - I'm actually using `-1` meter. I'm doing this to indicate that in the case when there is no origin point, it does not make sense to reason about the distance. Zero would also be a possible value, though that would fall within the "valid" range. I therefore chose `-1` to avoid confusion.

Comment: You seem to sum up +1 and -1 a fair amount - I'm not sure I follow. The only thing I can think of is `WHERE 1::int IS NULL`? In this case, I'm using the statement as a short circuit, to pick the `FROM` query I'm actually interested in, as this depends on what is originally an object (`WHERE ${filterModel.near && 1}::int IS NULL`) in javascript. This object can be either null or non-null.

Comment: OIC. Well, that brings us back to my "priority" remark. Sometimes we do not have a distance available, that's cool. But don't yield to the temptation to put some value into the `distance` column which is not, in fact, a distance. One of the hardest aspects of software engineering is naming. The names really matter. Choose accurate ones. Even if it starts out as some ugly `distance_or_preference`, which after you've stared at it for a while you decide to shorten to `priority` or a synonym.  We hate it when comments lie. It is worse when identifiers lie, so we go and fix them!

Comment: let your UI interface select rows WHERE longitude has some value - I want to avoid passing too much data over the wire. I prefer doing more work on the database side if that means passing 30 rows back rather than 1000.

Comment: And again, I really appreciate your work! I'm adding these comments as clarifications, but I'm very happy with the in-depth feedback!

Comment: put some value into the distance column which is not, in fact, a distance - well, it is a distance, just another kind of distance :) I'll think about alternatives but I'm probably pretty happy the way it is.

Comment: IDK where I got the notion we were adding distances from parent to child to child -- that is my error. I also failed to understand the role that "distance of negative one" plays in this -- I just assumed you must be subtracting 1 to rejigger a sort order, since negative distance doesn't make any sense. // For the positive 1, I was looking at `venue_parents` where it appeared we were starting an accumulator at 1, then there is `parent_query.distance + 1 AS distance` so it looked like we might be counting up how many steps from leaf to ancestor root. Generally, I found it unclear.

Comment: A column named `distance` is unambiguous: we use [SI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units), so it shall denote distance between a pair of specified points in meters. Not furlongs, not miles. We will need a longer identifier for either of those. If we choose to introduce some fancy distance metric that works along a bunch of dimensions, that's cool, but we'll need to document what "distance" means in that context. (Which is why we often hear "L-1 norm", "cosine distance", and related terms.)

Comment: Ah, ok. I was only thinking about the `WITH` query but sure, these are some complex queries - maybe I could introduce some more comments to clarify the `venue_parents` view :thinking:

Comment: Sooo, comments are nice and all. But honestly, I only believe half the comments I read. I trust well-named **identifiers** much more. And they force you to break up a Hard problem into a bunch of Easy problems, so you can apply some sensible name to each of the pieces. That's why I was advocating for turning the final query into composition of several VIEWs. // I really value the ability to `SELECT * FROM my_view` when debugging a query and when trying to understand the data. With several complex CTEs, I'm left with a lot of copy-n-pasting.

Comment: That's what I was trying to do by using more CTEs than necessary ("enumerated", "joined") but you may be right that VIEWs would be better, at least for some of these where reusability is of interest. (also, "enumerated" and "joined" are not all that good names - I see that).